# Using Cain and Abel to capture traffic of machine in the same network

Tags: network, privacy, network-scanners

I have installed Cain and Able in machine A, which is connected to another machine B via a LAN. Now I want to analyze all the traffic of machine B. Is this possible by installing Cain and Abel on machine A?

**EDIT**

After trying a bit more - Cain and Abel is able to sniff packets of the machine B. But the problem is how do I view the packets. It only shows the number of packets captured/sniffed, but doesn't actually let me see those packets.

Comment: why do you want to use Cain and Abel?

Comment: @schroeder : What do you mean by that? Are you suggesting any other alternative?

Comment: @Ashwin Alternative to do what? What do you expect Cain and Abel to do? What is your objective? If all you want to do is capture packets, then use tcpdump or Wireshark. My question is, what do you expect C&A to do?

Comment: @schroeder : I wanted cain and abel to posion system B. Then view the packets in wireshark. Any ways I got the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use Cain and Abel to become the man in the middle and then use wireshark to view the packets. Because wireshark can tell you what is happening in your `NIC(Network Interface Card)` i.e it can monitor the traffic of your machine's NIC. So you have to direct the other machines traffic to your NIC first(by becoming the `Man-in-Middle`). This can be done using Cain and Abel.

Comment: Nice! Cain for APR and Wireshark for packets inspection :D

Answer (score 6):

You can't: Cain and Abel is not a general purpose packet sniffer. Abel captures the packets, and then Cain performs analysis to try and find passwords; you look at the results of the analysis, not the raw packet capture.

If you want to view packets, you should use a more general product such as Wireshark.